# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' in C:\wamp\www\NewFirebase\Firebase.php on line 3

Tags: php, android, push-notification

sent push notification using `Firebas`e via `PHP` API.Parameter pass from the android and data get to push notification sent to android. Announcement get data from the database and its pass data in `Firebas`e class and its sent to notification in android.in line 3  whats error i don't Know.

Announcement.php

```
 <?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
        // $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
        // $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];

         require_once __DIR__ . '/firebase.php';
            require_once __DIR__ . '/push.php';

            $firebase = new Firebase();
            $push = new Push();


        $reg = $_GET['reg'];
        $fdate = $_GET['fdate'];
        $tdate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        //$tdate = date("2018-01-20");

        print_r($tdate);

        $date2 = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($fdate));
        $fdate1 =  date("Y-m-d", $date2);

        //print_r($fdate1);

         require_once('Demo.php');


        $sql = "select max(AnnounceDate) as  announcedate from AnnouncementTable";

        $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);  
        $result = array(); 

        $result["announcement"] = array();

        $result["success"] = 1;

        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

        $date1 = $row["announcedate"]->format('Y-m-d');
        $marks = array();

        $marks["announcedate"] = $row["announcedate"]->format('Y-m-d');

        array_push($result["announcement"], $marks);


        echo json_encode($result);

        print_r($date1);


        if ($date1 != $fdate){

        $check = "select * from
                            AnnouncementTable 
                            where  
                            AnnounceDate between '$fdate1' and '$tdate';select token from Std_Reg where RegNo='$reg'";

             $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$check);


            if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) > 0){



             while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){



                         $notiTitle = "Eurasian Infotech";
                         $clickEvent ="Announcement";
                         $notiMessage = $row["Title"];
                         $notiDescription = $row["Description"];
                         $regId = $row['token'];

                         $push->setTitle($notiTitle);
                         $push->setMessage($notiMessage);
                         $push->setClickevent($clickEvent);
                         $push->setAnnounce($notiDescription);

                         $json = '';
                         $response = '';

                         $json = $push->getPush();
                         $response = $firebase->send($regId,$json);
                            //sendNotification($notiTitle, $notiMessage,$reg,$date1); 
                echo "sucessfully added";
                     }
                }else{
                echo "error in sending request";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Sent Notification";
                }

        }else{
        echo 'error';
    }



    ?>
```

Firebase.php

```
<?php

class Firebase(){

    public function send($to,$message){
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

        require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

push.php

```
<?php

class Push{


    private $title;
    private $message;
    private $date;
    private $announce;
    private $clickevent;

    function _construct(){

    }


    public function setTitle($title){

    }

    public function setMessage($message){

    }

    public function setDate($date){

    }

    public function setAnnounce($announce){

    }

    public function setClickevent($clickevent){

    }

    public function getPush(){

        $res = array();
        $res['data']['title'] = $this->title;
        $res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
        $res['data']['date'] = $this->date('Y-m-d');
        $res['data']['announce'] = $this->announce;
        $res['data']['clickevent'] = $this->clickevent;
        $res['data']['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        return $res;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: What happens when you move `require_once` outside of the `if` statement?

Comment: its give same error.

Comment: And is `firebase.php` something you've created yourself or something that was provided as part of the framework? Can you post the first few lines of it here?

Comment: Remove the '()' in line 3 so it looks like `class Firebase {`